# What are the different kinds of endpoint Lightning nodes a user can choose from and their trade-offs?

Tags: lightning-network

What are the different kinds of endpoint Lightning nodes a user can choose when joining the Lightning Network and their trade-offs?

(Note this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106015/what-are-the-different-kinds-of-lightning-routing-nodes) is not a duplicate as it attempts a classification of different routing nodes rather than endpoint nodes.)

Answer (score 1):

Christian Decker answered this at [Advancing Bitcoin 2022](https://btctranscripts.com/advancing-bitcoin/2022/2022-03-03-christian-decker-greenlight/).

[image: christian diagram]

> Custodial wallets are then further split into
> account based and hosted channels, sometimes also called multi-tenancy
> systems, built on top of a single Lightning node that is under the
> control of some operator.
>
> On the non-custodial side we have the
> self hosted version which has been so far the go-to case for many of
> you I believe. In that case you have to learn about how to operate a
> Lightning node, how to set up all of the infrastructure: databases,
> watchtowers, backups etc. If I drop my phone in the lake what do I do
> now? With great flexibility comes a lot of responsibility as well.
>
> Then we have the split into do we want to have a node per device? That
> is often a choice that has been made so far where we build a node into
> the Lightning application. There are now really good tools to do that,
> LDK is an excellent example of how to do that, but it also means that
> if you use more than one app you are now operating two wallets. You
> are splitting funds across these two wallets. If you have 50 here and
> 50 here you can’t pay 60. There is no way of combining them. It also
> means that the management overhead that you have is multiplied by the
> number of apps that you have. If you have two apps you now have to
> manage twice the number of channels, you have to manage twice the
> number of backups, you have to pay twice the watchtowers and so on and
> so forth. It also means that if you drop your phone in the lake, bye
> bye funds basically.
>
> Then there is the remote control node scenario
> where you have some sort of box at home. You are remoting into that
> node from the outside. Personally I quite like this because it means
> that I can have multiple apps be frontends to the same node. The funds
> are concentrated on a single node and I don’t run into this issue that
> I might not be able to pay an invoice despite having sufficient funds,
> if only they were combinable. The upside is I can drop my phone in the
> lake again and my funds are still safe. That’s kind of nice.
>
> Today I am going to present a mix between these scenarios. That is what I call
> remote control and remote signer. We will see how this can be used to
> get the best of both worlds. Make it easier to assist new users until
> they have learnt about the Lightning Network to take on responsibility
> for their own node and how they can migrate from this scenario over to
> this scenario. It enables a lot of flexibility and at a later point in
> time, once you have seen the upside of what this can do for you, you
> are incentivized to learn and upgrade your experience to take care of
> your own node. What I didn’t mention is that remote controlled node
> and remote control/remote signer setups also have a way smaller
> capture feature. Namely if you integrate the node into the app then
> you don’t have the flexibility of trying out the new app that might
> have a new cool interface. You have to tear down the entire node,
> transfer funds and then spin up the entire node again just to find out
> this UI actually doesn’t work for me so I’ll migrate back. With the
> remote setups you can switch between front ends and even use them
> concurrently as often as you want. You could have the same node be
> fronted by a web browser and a mobile app. Or you could give your kids
> access to parts of that node in the form of an allowance for example.

[Greenlight](https://blog.blockstream.com/en-greenlight-by-blockstream-lightning-made-easy/) is an example of the remote control / signer option. It is a service provided by Blockstream but others are free to provide similar services.